# Проблема с получением значения нужного атрибута

Tags: html, jquery, ajax, json

При клике на элемент, через алерт должно возвратится значение атрибута , элемента по которому кликнули.Но проблема в том , что всегда возвращается первый элемент из списка а не тот по которому кликнули.

Использую плагин autocomplect может он мешает ?

вот код обработчика :

```
      open: function( event, ui ) {$( "li" ).click(function() {
        alert($( "li[data-context-key]" ).attr("data-context-key"))
     });
```

вот весь код демонстрирующий проблему (нужно нажать "л") http://jsfiddle.net/t52ka/86/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В функцию которая вызывается по клику передается параметр типа `Event`, это написано в [документации](https://api.jquery.com/click/). Т.е. вам надо взять этот параметр и из него получить элемент по которому кликнули. Обычно это что-то типа `e.currentTarget`, ваш код в таком случае будет выглядеть:

```
open: function( event, ui ) {$( "li" ).click(function(e) {
    alert($( e.currentTarget ).attr("data-context-key"))
 });
```

Comment: Спасибо работает)

Answer (score 3):

> $( "li[data-context-key]" )

Находит все элементы li с аттрибутом data-context-key. Вместо этого следует использовать this. Попробуйте так:

```
alert($(this).attr("data-context-key"))
```

Comment: Это решение, думаю, гораздо лаконичные чем таргет